# With the release of iOS 11.2.1 an essential feature of my Apple TV was removed

Tags: appletv, homekit

I have an 3rd generation Apple TV which I use as a [home hub](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207057). After remote access was disabled from Apple because of [CVE-2017-13903](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208357) and turned on again with iOS 11.2.1 it stopped working remotely for shared users with the Apple TV.

Here are the changes to HT207057:
[image]
This is the version of  Dec 15, 2017.

And here the version of Mar 27, 2017 as it looked on [Sep 27, 2017](https://web.archive.org/web/20170923205625/https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207057):
[image]

I am a bit unhappy about this because I don't really use the Apple TV for watching, so it would be a bit overkill to buy a 4K one. What could I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can buy an Apple TV 4 (not 4K), which is cheaper. Or if you have an iPad model that can be updated to iOS 11 (which is Air/Air 2, 5th gen or newer, or mini 2 or newer) use that as your home hub.

Otherwise you are out of luck. Even if 3rd generation Apple TV had a jailbreak available (it does not) to patch this feature back in, you're talking about encrypted communication between Apple devices and Apple's servers, which is extremely unlikely to be able to be replicated by a third party to reenable it.

Comment: Well the Apple TV 4 just 3 years younger than the third generation. So if I am unlucky soon it will stop working too. There is no stationary iPad, so this is also no solution. And I don't want to replace speakers either.

Comment: I think I read somewhere about HAP over iCloud. So that the device can connect directly to the cloud without an hub. But I never found a documentation. Is there such a thing?

Comment: [Here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/210/) it is mentioned. It is on slide 153. But I never saw it anywhere.

Comment: Yes, it works through iCloud - that's how they were able to remotely disable shared access until they could release patch. But you still have to have a device that's capable of accessing that information in iCloud, which as it stands is iPads on iOS 11 or Apple TV 4 or later.

Comment: But if you look at page 147 and then 149pp. It suggests that you don't need an iPad or Apple TV, right?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that all of your iOS devices are running iOS 11.2.1 or newer. Even if your Apple TV is up to date, your iOS devices also need to be updated in order for HomeKit sharing to work completely.

Comment: How does it help? I also could set up every device as a new or do whatever stupid thing AppleCare suggest?

Comment: As you said tvOS 11.2.1 restores HomeKit hub capabilities, iOS 11.2.1 is also required for this to work. It included a a similar security fix.

Comment: So how can I install tvOS on a 3rd gen Apple TV?

Comment: @Jake3231 The key here is the user has a 3rd generation Apple TV which does not run tvOS. Updating other devices to the latest iOS version is not going to change that.